# Changing system date

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to change the system date in Ubuntu 12.04.

I tried:

```
$ date -s "2 OCT 2006 18:00:00" 
Mon Oct  2 18:00:00 IST 2006
date changed.
```

But after some time, or when I reboot the system, the current date and time display becomes:

```
Wed Aug  1 10:55:32 IST 2012
```

I want to display the changed time in the preview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NTP is probably correcting your system time. If you want to set your time to something other than what's currently close to correct, stop ntp and stop it from starting up and syncing on system startup.